# Change the Background of MS Excel 2003

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm a c# coder and so far this is the best way I know to express what I wanted.
I am thinking of doing this code below on a microsoft excel 2003 worksheet.
Could this be possible?

**1st step**

```
if(CellA1 == "Sunday" || CellA1== "Saturday"){
    // code to set background color of 
    // CellB1 to CellF1 to background color red
}
```

**2nd step**

```
// Execute this process from CellA1 until CellA10    
for(CellA1 up to CellA10){
    // do first step
}
```

So the code I wanted to do on MSExcel 2003 would look like this

```
for(int CellCount = 1;CellCount<10;CellCount++){

    if("CellA"+CellCount.ToString() == "Sunday" || 
       "CellA"+CellCount.ToString() == "Sunday"){

        // set ["CellB"+CellCount.ToString()].CellBackgroundColor="#FF0000";
        // set ["CellC"+CellCount.ToString()].CellBackgroundColor="#FF0000";
        // set ["CellD"+CellCount.ToString()].CellBackgroundColor="#FF0000";
        // set ["CellE"+CellCount.ToString()].CellBackgroundColor="#FF0000";
        // set ["CellF"+CellCount.ToString()].CellBackgroundColor="#FF0000";
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible. Or if there are any other ways equivalent on what I wanted to do, can you please help me. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub backcolor()
Range("a1:a10").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
For Each cell In Range("a1:a10")
    If cell.Value = "Sunday" Or cell.Value = "Saturday" Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

You can find the list of colors here

http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is change the color of a cell based on its value, just use conditional formatting in excel, no need for any programming.

Comment: Second that: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-conditional-formatting-formulas-HA001111661.aspx

Comment: they might be reading , but not have control over the source file